# freemarker nested segments dont find scripts in my master page

Tags: jquery, html, spring, freemarker, template-engine

hi i'm working with a spring mvc project using freemarker as my template engine i created a master page using macros and put the new content in a nested tag inside my macro page like this:

myMacroPage.html i import all my scripts in the head.html fragment

```
<#macro masterPageLay>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

    <#include "layout/head.html"/>
    <#include "layout/menu.html"/>
    <#nested>
    <#include "layout/footer.html"/>

</html>
</#macro>
```

my nestedPage.html

```
<form id="checkout-form">
   ..... form that use JQuery methods
</form>
 <!-- PAGE RELATED PLUGIN(S) -->
    <script src="resources/js/plugin/jquery-form/jquery-form.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/scripts/formValidator.js"></script>
```

this give me the following errors: `JQuery is tno defined` and `$is not defined`

but if i put the page related scripts in my macroPage works fine, but i dont want to put all the scripts in my macro maste page since not all the pages uses the same scripts i want to put the scripts in each page, but it gives me that error

Comment: I'm not sure if it's clear: FreeMarker runs on the server, jQuery runs on the client (in the browser). So, check the source view in your browser, and you will see exactly what's going on.

Comment: i checked the chrome console and there was those two errors  `JQuery is not defined` and `$is not defined` and if i put this in  `<!-- PAGE RELATED PLUGIN(S) -->
    <script src="resources/js/plugin/jquery-form/jquery-form.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/scripts/formValidator.js"></script>`  in my macroPage works fine, but i dont want to put all the scripts in my macro maste page since not all the pages uses the same scripts i want to put the scripts in each page, but it gives me that error

Comment: What I'm saying is that the FTL templates are irrelevant, at least in the first iteration. What's wrong with the output HTML page is what need to be answered first. Hence, see that in browser source view first.

Comment: @ddekany what is  `browser source view first`? are the concole javascript errors that i mention? beacuse my client (browser) dont show any views error since the problem is that my browser dont find the jquery library, i think is because freemarker exclude that nested secction from my master page and in my master page is where i import my jquery library

Comment: He means view the source of the page. It's `Ctrl + U` in Chrome.

Comment: Are you using `<#ftl strip_text=true />` at the top of your page? It sounds like the paths are just wrong.